# Dialogflow Messenger's custom payload for web links does not work

Tags: web, hyperlink, payload

Why can't the custom payload of the following Web link be displayed under DialogFlow Messenger?

[image]

Comment: In fact, Even adding  “richContent”  command in custom payload(It still  not show up in DF Messenger response)



{
   "richContent":{
    "web" : {
    “text”:“check  the  website",
    "type": "hyperlink",
    "link": "https://www.ets.org/toeic/test-takers/listening-reading/preparation"
  }
   }
}

Answer (score 2):

Can you please try with below custom payload. Looks like it's work for me.

```
 {
   "richContent": [
   [
  {
    "actionLink": "https://example.com",
    "title": "Info item title",
    "type": "info"
  }
 ]
]
}
```

[image]

So On clicking on the **Info Item Title** It's redirect to the specified link.

Let me know if you have any confusion.

Ref: https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/es/docs/integrations/dialogflow-messenger

Comment: Dhruv Rajkotia;
Many thanks. It works well and a good way to replace a website with info card.